# How do I display local image in markdown?

Tags: image, markdown

Does anyone know how to display a local image in markdown? I don't want to set up a webserver for that.

I try the following in markdown, but it doesn't work:

`![image](files/Users/jzhang/Desktop/Isolated.png)`

Comment: Note: if you have spaces in the file path, they have to be url-encoded or the link won't work in some systems (e.g. GitHub).

Comment: `![image](files://C:/Users/jzhang/Desktop/Isolated.png)`

Answer (score 747):

I suspect the path is not correct. As mentioned by user7412219 ubuntu and windows deal with path differently. Try to put the image in the same folder as your Notebook and use:

```
![alt text](Isolated.png "Title")
```

On windows the desktop should be at: `C:\Users\jzhang\Desktop`

Comment: What does "Title" do?

Comment: @niCkcAMel "Title" is what is shown if you hover your mouse over the image. "alt text" is what is shown, instead, if the image cannot be displayed.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to add to change the image size. The following command should work: ```<img src="Isolated.png" alt="isolated" width="200"/>```

Comment: @jb12n thats HTML not MD.

Comment: @bytedev HTML is perfectly fine [in Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#html).

Comment: @9769953 that's just the application allowing HTML. HTML is HTML and MD is MD :-)

Comment: @bytedev I'm just stating that (inline) HTML is perfectly fine in Markdown. So that solution for image size, albeit HTML, works fine in a Markdown document, and thus (while only a comment), answers the question/adds to this (and other) answer correctly. (In fact, it may be the only solution to set an image size in a Markdown documention).

Comment: For what it's worth, not ALL Markdown flavors accept HTML, or if they do, they only accept certain white-listed tags with certain white-listed properties.

Comment: That is because the inventor of Markdown did not set a standard, we have many flavors. Raw html is still widely supported.
pandoc md flavor supports html, see: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#raw-html
Github flavor also supports html (since gfm is a strict superset of commonmark, superset of markdown), see: https://github.github.com/gfm/#raw-html

Comment: Hi, when my images is loacated at the same location as the md file it works, but in my case the images would be at ../ressources/image.jpg but that does not work... what am I missing? So it is located in a parallel folder to the md file.

Comment: To change width or height you can do the following: `![alt text](filepath/filename){width=x height=y}`. You can specify only width or only height to maintain aspect ratio. For example `![apple](./images/apple.png){width=200}`

Answer (score 405):

The following works with a relative path to an image into a subfolder next to the document:

```
![image info](./pictures/image.png)
```

Comment: IMHO the best answer, works with a GitHub markdown file in the desired manner.

Comment: `![image info](pictures/image.png)` also works

Comment: Plus spaces will be with %20 like
path/to/image dir/place  -> path/to/image%20dir/place

Answer (score 81):

#### Solution for **Unix-like** operating system.

STEP BY STEP :

1. Create a directory named like `Images` and put all the images that will be rendered by the Markdown.
2. For example, put `example.png` into `Images`.
3. To load `example.png` that was located under the  `Images` directory before.

```
![title](Images/example.png)
```

***Note*** :  `Images` directory must be located under the same directory of your markdown text file which has `.md` extension.

Comment: What is the path of that "Images" folder? Did you add it to any config in vscode?

Comment: @K_dev  "images" directory must be located under the same directory of your markdown text file which has ".md" extension. I did not add any config to vscode.

Comment: Works fine with Jupyter Notebooks :-)

Comment: ensure no spaces in filename

Comment: I don't think this solution is UNIX-like only..

Comment: I didn't state that it will not work any other operating system. Filesystem and its path resolutions algorithms are unique for each OS. Some OSs can resemble each other, it is natural.

Answer (score 30):

To add an image in markdown file the .md file and the image should be in the same directory. As in my case my .md file was in doc folder so i also moved the image into the same folder. After that write the following syntax in .md file

```
![alt text](filename)
```

like `![Car Image](car.png)`

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

The best solution is to provide a path relative to the folder where the md document is located.

Probably a browser is in trouble when it tries to resolve the absolute path of a local file. That can be solved by accessing the file trough a webserver, but even in that situation, the image path has to be right.

Having a folder at the same level of the document, containing all the images, is the cleanest and safest solution. 
It will load on GitHub, local, local webserver.

```
images_folder/img.jpg  < works


/images_folder/img.jpg  < this will work on webserver's only (please read the note!)
```

Using the absolute path, the image will be accessible only with a url like this: http://hostname.doesntmatter/image_folder/img.jpg

Comment: +1 for "The best solution is to provide a path relative to the folder where the md document is located." It showed the images on my local machine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Eleventy version 2..0.1. Regardless of how I put it in (and the image directory is copied to the output directory) it doesn't want to load the image.

Answer (score 22):

if image has bracket it won't display

```
![alt text](Isolated(1).png)
```

rename the image and remove brackets

```
![alt text](Isolated-1.png)
```

Update:
if you have spaces in the file path, you should consider renaming it too or if you use JavaScript you can encode it using

```
encodeURIComponent(imagePath)
```

*Also, always try to save images and files alike with lowercase, please develop that habit, just my personal view though*

Comment: I do agree on the pieces of advice but, technically, brackets and spaces in file names are allowed if [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) is used, as in `![image (2).png](image%20%282%29.png)`.

Answer (score 18):

Adding a local image worked for me by like so: `![alt text](file://IMG_20181123_115829.jpg)`

Without the `file://` prefix it did not work (Win10, Notepad++ with MarkdownViewer++ addon)

Edit: I found out it also works with html tags, and that is way better:
`<img src="file://IMG_20181123_115829.jpg" alt="alt text" width="200"/>`

Edit2: In Atom editor it *only* works without the `file://` prefix. What a mess.

Answer (score 14):

Just add the relative image file route from the markdown file

```
![localImage](./client/src/assets/12.png)
```

Answer (score 12):

Depending on your tool - you can also inject HTML into markdown.

```
<img src="./img/Isolated.png">
```

This assumes your folder structure is:

```
 ├── img
     └── Isolated.jpg
 ├── README.md
```

Comment: Only this worked for me on VSCode markdown display

Comment: This is good also for specifying other parameters like `width` or `height` ..

Answer (score 9):

Edited:

### Working for me ( for local image )

```
![system schema](doc/systemDiagram.jpg)

 tree
 ├── doc
     └── jobsSystemSchema.jpg
 ├── README.md
```

markdown file README.md is at the same level as doc directory.

In your case ,your markdown file should be at the same level as the directory files.

### Working for me (absolute url with raw path)

```
![system schema](https://server/group/jobs/raw/master/doc/systemDiagram.jpg)
```

### NOT working for me  (url with blob path)

```
![system schema](https://server/group/jobs/blob/master/doc/systemDiagram.jpg)
```

Comment: I think that your url is not valid:
There's one slash missing after https. A bit late, maybe. :)

Comment: Thanks @Funder, I correct the the url , it was a miss typing .  

Comment: I had success with the blob path, when accessing the image from a MD file hosted on github.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me in ubuntu:

```
![Image](/home/gps/Pictures/test.png "a title")
```

Markdown file is in:

```
/home/gps/Documents/Markdown/
```

Image file is in:

```
/home/gps/Pictures/
```

Answer (score 7):

In [Jupyter Notebook Markdown](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html), you can use

```
<img src="RelPathofFolder/File" style="width:800px;height:300px;">
```

Comment: did quick edit (and typo fix) to help readability, should be right link but worth checking in case :)

Comment: Pro: added HTML customization using `<img >` tag

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, for VSCode on Linux, the local image can be normally displayed only when you put the image into the same folder as your `.md` post file.
i.e. only `![](image.jpg)` or `![](./image.jpg)` will work.
Even the absolute path like `![](/home/bala/image.jpg)`also doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility for not displayed local image is **unintentional indent** of the image reference - spaces before `![alt text](file)`.

This makes it 'code block' instead of 'image inclusion'. Just remove the leading spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You may find following the syntax similar to [reference links in markdown](https://sourceforge.net/p/pollen/discussion/markdown_syntax#md_ex_reflinks) handy, especially when you have a text with many displays of the same image:

```
![optional text description of the image][number]

[number]: URL
```

For example:

```
![][1]

![This is an optional description][2]




[1]: /home/jerzy/ComputerScience/Parole/Screenshot_2020-10-13_11-53-29.png
[2]: /home/jerzy/ComputerScience/Parole/Screenshot_2020-10-13_11-53-30.png
```

Answer (score 2):

just copy the image and then paste it, you will get the output

```
![image.png](attachment:image.png)
```

Comment: Probably the only way to show images on both local Jupyter Notebooks and Github renderer when the images are not placed in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Either put the image in the same folder as the markdown file or use a relative path to the image.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with inserting images in R Markdown. If I do the entire URL: `C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Project/images/image.png` it tends to work. Otherwise, I have to put the markdown in either the same directory as the image or in an ancestor directory to it. It appears that the declared knitting directory is ignored when referencing images.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Shanteshwar Although phrased as a problem, this offers a working solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

## Displaying local images in .md file (VSCode reader extension)

In my case, I tried a lot of solutions to display an image in my vscode .md reader, but none of them works. But it appears that it only works when you specify the full path to the image from the root for example:
`![My image](/c:/fullpath/to/image.png)`.
**The trick is you need to specify / before the letter c of your drive**

Answer (score 0):

For me working fine with gitlab when I have specified URL to image started from ./

Please double-check that you don't have the space between [] and ()

```
![img] (URL)
      ^
```

Sometimes very confusing.

Answer (score -3):

I got a solution:

a) Example Internet:

```
![image info e.g. Alt](URL Internet to Images.jpg "Image Description")
```

b) Example local Image:

```
![image Info](file:///<Path to your File><image>.jpg "Image Description")
![image Info](file:///C:/Users/<name>/Pictures/<image>.jpg "Image Description")
```

TurboByte