# How do I add image to README file on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

The title says it all. I took a look into GitLab docs but couldn't find clear-cut solution to this.

How do I add image to readme on GitLab ? Image that's within the repo.

Comment: Try using [IMAGE_DESCRIPTION](url_of_image)

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display local image in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604263/how-to-display-local-image-in-markdown)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `![IMAGE_DESCRIPTION](url_of_image)`

Answer (score 16):

You can use `![image info](images/image.png)` where images could be a directory in your project structure.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#images)

```
Inline-style (hover to see title text):

![alt text](img/markdown_logo.png "Title Text")

Reference-style (hover to see title text):

![alt text1][logo]

[logo]: img/markdown_logo.png "Title Text"
```

Comment: Ohh .. OK. I didn't bump into this page. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: That works in Issues, not in README.md, at least not for an image in the repository, as OP asked.

Answer (score -1):

for more info. create issue and upload image /copy url of image to IMAGE_DESCRIPTION

Answer (score -1):

**BEST AND EASIEST WAY:**

USE *HTML ELEMENT: like this*

```
<img src="https://github.com/user/repo/blob/main/output.jpg" align="center" height="350" width="600"/>
```

This will allow to control Height/Width/Allignment too.