# Adding local image in Jupyter SQL notebook

Tags: sql-server, image, jupyter-notebook, azure-data-studio

Started using Azure data studio and creating documentation for some SQL processes in our system.

As part of that I need to include a flow diagram in the document. Currently I have uploaded an image to a URL and am able to embed the image in document from the URL.

But is there any way to include an image from a local folder? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in this also.  Syntax should be (if you store images in subfolder relative to notebook):

```
![ssms_subquery](images/16_ssms_subquery.png)
```

This didn't work for me initially: rendered as a broken image icon.

Things I tried:

- Make sure you have a workspace defined for your root folder.  Create the folder, then select "File > Add Folder to Workspace ..."
- If that does nothing, try closing and restarting ADS.  I've found the rendering to be flaky from time to time after awhile or if you have been opening/closing notebooks a lot.

Related topic has been discussed previously for markdown in general (but worth asking again for ADS!), eg. [How to display local image in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604263/how-to-display-local-image-in-markdown)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want.

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='C:/your_path/your_image.PNG',width=200, height=100)
```

Comment: i doubt that it will work for sql notebook of jupyter. Note : Kernal = SQL. not python