# jupyter markdown cell Image insertion difficulties

Tags: markdown

I am trying to insert an image in a markdown cell, but nothing works.

I am creating a report in a different ipython kernel, so the images were downloaded different codes but it's not working

I have tried the following:

- `<img src="files/C:\Users\chikaodili\Downloads/Total_number_of_Retweets_for_each_dog_type.png">`
- `<img src="files/Total_number_of_Retweets_for_each_dog_type.png">`
- `![Total number of Retweets for dog type](Total number of Retweets for each dog type.png)`
- `![Total number of Retweets for dog type]("Total number of Retweets for each dog type.png")`

nothing works!

Comment: Check your image location. You should also avoid using spaces in file paths.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41912122/18990321